# Neo4J deep validate graph

Tags: neo4j

DB have  some amount of OrderItemType   which have relations between  one to another like  INCOMPATIBLE and REQUIRED

We combining an order  by linking OrderItemType to it with CONTAINS relation

Is it possible to make constraint to  fail  with validation error  when trying to add new  OrderItemType which is incompatible with another in graph and if required items is not present yet?

Target is just trying to insert, and  get reject if it violate some conditions

Another option - using transaction:
1. insert item
2. load graph and check rules manually
3. rollback if find some  problems

**UPDATE**
Ok I will rephrase question with standard  movies sample

lets establish some relations  between actors

```
CREATE (Keanu)-[:HATE]->(JackN),
(Keanu)-[:REQUIRE]->(LillyW),
(JamesM)-[:HATE]->(LillyW)
```

now we starting  new movie producing

```
CREATE (RaiseOfCrazyDev:Movie {title:'RaiseOfCrazyDev', released:2020, tagline:'Crazy developer  conquer the world'})
```

and start casting. first we sign **JackN**, and  **JamesM**

```
CREATE (JackN)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Father']} ]->(RaiseOfCrazyDev),
(JamesM)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['BadGuy']} ]->(RaiseOfCrazyDev)
```

now we try to sign **Keanu**

```
CREATE (Keanu)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Dev']} ]->(RaiseOfCrazyDev)
```

But it should fail, since **Keanu** *hates* **JackN**, and **Keanu** *require*  **LillyW**

so we remove JackN and add Keanu  and LillyW instead

```
MATCH (:JackN)-[r:ACTED_IN]-(:RaiseOfCrazyDev) DELETE r
CREATE (Keanu)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Dev']} ]->(RaiseOfCrazyDev),
(LillyW)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['StepSister']} ]->(RaiseOfCrazyDev)
```

but now it fails again because **JamesM** *hates* **LillyW**

since Keanu is  a main role  in our movie, we fire JamesM

```
MATCH (:JamesM)-[r:ACTED_IN]-(:RaiseOfCrazyDev) DELETE r
```

So, if rephrase:

- It should be no HATE relationship  between any two actors attached to one  movie
- For all actors their REQUIRE relationship should be actors in this movie too.

Question: What is the best way and place to make such  conditions checks?

Comment: Can you provide a Cypher query that generates some data in your data model?

Comment: added example based on movie sample

Comment: Can the DB contain problematic situations like: `a` requires `b`, and `b` requires `c`, but `c` hates `a`? Or would you prevent such situations from being introduced?

Comment: prevent.  Error should happens with  enough details and UI will resolve  problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that problematic situations like the following do not exist in the DB: `a` requires `b`, and `b` requires `c`, but `c` hates `a`. (Even though such situations can exist in real life :-)). I also assume that actor nodes have the `Actor` label and a `name` property.

This query should get you started. It will tell you if it is OK to add an actor (I assume that `actorName` and `title` are passed as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/parameters/)). It will also return a list of the current cast members opposed by the "required" actors (including the main actor you want to add, and all the actors required by the required actors, etc.), and a list of the required actors opposed by the current cast members:

```
MATCH (a:Actor {name: $actorName}), (m:Movie {title: $title})
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(a)-[:REQUIRE*]->(:Actor)
WITH a, m, NODES(p) AS reqs
UNWIND reqs AS req
WITH DISTINCT a, m, reqs, req
OPTIONAL MATCH (req)-[:HATE]->(h:Actor)
WITH a, m, reqs, COLLECT(DISTINCT h) AS hatedByReq
OPTIONAL MATCH (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(x:Actor)
OPTIONAL MATCH (x)-[:HATE]->(y:Actor)
WITH a, m, reqs, hatedByReq, COLLECT(x) AS cast, COLLECT(DISTINCT y) AS hatedByCast
WITH a, m, [c IN cast WHERE c IN hatedByReq] AS reqOpposes, [r IN reqs WHERE r IN hatedByCast] AS castOpposes
RETURN a, m, reqOpposes, castOpposes, (SIZE(reqOpposes) = 0 AND SIZE(castOpposes) = 0) AS okToAddActors
```

The result, using your sample data, is:

```
╒════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════╤═══════════════════╤═══════════════╕
│"a"             │"m"                                                                   │"reqOpposes"      │"castOpposes"      │"okToAddActors"│
╞════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│{"name":"Keanu"}│{"title":"RaiseOfCrazyDev","tagline":"Crazy developer  conquer the wor│[{"name":"JackN"}]│[{"name":"LillyW"}]│false          │
│                │ld","released":2020}                                                  │                  │                   │               │
└────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: In order to have the query actually create the new relationships (assuming there is no opposition), you'd have to somehow supply the roles for *every required actor* that is not already in the cast. You will have to think about how to do that. I think this answer above is the best that can be done, without that info.